# React state to hide a div flashes the div using local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to create a div that user can hide with a button in react next.js. But the problem is that on reload, the div is shown for a few second and it flashes.

```js
const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem('STATE');
    if (data !== null) setShowBanner(JSON.parse(data));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('STATE', JSON.stringify(showBanner));
  }, [showBanner]);
```

and this is how I am doing a conditional rendering:

```js
{showBanner && (
          <div>
            <div>
              <h2>Welcome</h2>
              <p>Sign up for my newsletter</p>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => setShowBanner(false)}>Hide</button>
          </div>
        )}
```

https://s9.gifyu.com/images/Dec-16-2022-13-16-27.gif

Here is a working sandbox:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-yvskoq?file=pages/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the initial state to the localStorage value if it exists:

```
const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const data = window.localStorage.getItem('STATE');
  if (data !== null) setShowBanner(JSON.parse(data));
  else setShowBanner(true);
}, []);
```

Comment: thanks, this would give "ReferenceError: window is not defined"

Comment: The `window` object is not accessible outside `useEffect` in NextJS

Comment: then you'll probably want to default to false, and then set it to true inside useEffect if data === null